# XML Delphi - Mismatch in datapacket

Tags: delphi, xml

Estou avaliando um sistema feito em Delphi 6, que basicamente utiliza um TClientDataSet para abrir arquivos xml.

Este sistema já funciona a muito tempo e está Ok, apenas um arquivo xml está indicando o erro de "Mismatch in datapacket" quando tento abri-lo.

A principio não estou postando o xml aqui pois ele tem mais de 1200 campos, e como só com um arquivo está gerando erro, acredito que a estrutura do xml esteja correta.

Deve haver alguma informação errada digitada pelo usuário, porém, não consigo encontrar.

No delphi não consigo debugar pois o erro já ocorre na hora de abrir o xml.

Existe algum software que possa indicar onde está este erro?
Alguma sugestão de como localizar onde está o problema?

Fiz algumas tentativas de analisa no XML Mapper do próprio Delphi, mas não consegui localizar nada.

Abaixo link para download do XML. Infelizmente não posso postar o arquivo com problema pois tem muitas informações comerciais. O arquivo abaixo é para mostrar como é a estrutura do arquivo.

[Link download XML](https://we.tl/BQ8mueldRj)

Comment: Ficou esquisita a sua analise. Se o erro só ocorre com esse xml, é bem provável que o xml esteja com problema. Quando você diz 1200 campos, você se refere as tags do xml ou é um arquivo xls com 1200 linhas ?

Comment: É um arquivo xml com 1200 tags. E sim, você está certo, o problema é mesmo com este xml, porém, preciso encontrar onde está o defeito, para verificar depois se foi o software que gera ele que criou este defeito.

Comment: Poderia postar o xml? Talvez o link dele.

Comment: Adicionei link para um xml vazio mas com a mesma estrutura. Pelo teor dos dados não posso postar o arquivo original.

Comment: Geralmente esse erro ocorre quando a incompatibilidade de tipos. Ex.: Um campo `inteiro` recebendo um valor `string`. Como falei, _geralmente_, ou seja, pode ser outro problema.

Comment: O xml vazio não funciona também? Se esse for o caso, então a estrutura dele não é válida para um TClientDataset.

Comment: tem uma tag <PARAMS/> no fim do arquivo. Remove esse cara e tenta importar o xml.

Comment: o xml vazio funciona. Removendo o tag não muda o erro. Tem realmente algum dado errado. Ninguém conhece algum software que possa ajudar nesta analise?

Comment: Cara, fica difícil sem o xml. Se você conseguir simular o problema em um outro xml, ficaria melhor.

Comment: Eu abri o arquivo no XML Mapper do Delphi para tirar algumas informações importantes e postar o arquivo, mas antes fiz somente um salvar como para testar, e o erro sumiu. O XML ficou com o dobro do tamanho, mas agora está funcionado. Vou ficar sem saber qual era o problema, mas tem uma solução. Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar.

Comment: Crie várias cópias desse arquivo xml com problema e cada cópia com apenas uma tag com seu respectivo valor.
Carregue cada arquivo, talvez você vai descobrir em que tag está o problema.